# Python abstract attribute and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

Say I have the following code:

```
class Archive(object):
    """ Archiv-File wrapper """
    READ_MODE = 0
    WRITE_MODE = 1

    def __init__(self, file_):
        self.file_ = file_
        self._mode = None

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode

    @mode.setter
    def mode(self, value):
        self._mode = value

    def open(self, mode="r", pwd=None):
        raise NotImplemented("Subclasses should implement this method!")

    def close(self):
        raise NotImplemented("Subclasses should implement this method!")

################################################

class GzipGPGArchive(Archive):
    READ_MODE = 'r:gz'  # Open for reading with gzip compression.
    WRITE_MODE = 'w:gz'  # Open for gzip compressed writing.
    SUFFIX = "tar.gz.gpg"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GzipGPGArchive, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @mode.setter # This causes unresolved reference
    def mode(self, value):
        # do internal changes
        self._mode = value

    def open(self):
        pass

    def close(self):
        pass
```

so know what is the best pythonic way to override the setter and getter method of the Abstract class attribute `mode`.

Overriding `@mode.setter` in the sub-class `GzipGPGArchive` causes unresolved reference!

Comment: You might want to initialize `self._mode` in the initializer (`__init__`), otherwise after creating an instance you try to read the property (before setting it) you'll get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @CristiFati corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as abstract attributes in Python. You can achieve abstraction, however, by using `abc` module. Perhaps it is not really "*pythonic*", but it works.

This is the minimal example with inheritance and abstraction. Use it as as template:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Mother(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def method_(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def property_(self):
        return -1

    @property_.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def property_(self, value):
        pass

class Daughter(Mother):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value_ = 0

    def method_(self):
        print(self.value_)

    @property
    def property_(self):
        return = self.value_

    @property_.setter
    def property_(self, value):
        self.value_ = value
```

Comment: this worked for me, BUT what is really the right pythonic to doing such a things???